# How to exclude a class from a library implemented in dependencies? android

Tags: java, android, zegocloud

I just implemented this library, which is essential for the app to work:

```
implementation 'com.github.ZEGOCLOUD:zego_uikit_prebuilt_call_android:2.1.2'
```

The problem is that after its implementation I get this error:

```
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in modules annotation-1.5.0 (androidx.annotation: annotation:1.5.0) and jetified-annotation-jvm-1.7.0-alpha02 (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.0-alpha02)
```

That's because I have this dependency implemented too, which I think is the one that is colliding with me:

```
'androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7. 0-alpha02'
```

What I want is to exclude the ANNOTATION class from the ZEGOCLOUD library as shown below, the problem is that it doesn't work for me this way!

```
implementation ('com.github.ZEGOCLOUD:zego_uikit_prebuilt_call_android:2.1.2') {
    exclude group: 'androidx.annotation', module: 'annotation-jvm'
}
```

Does anyone know how I can find out the exact name of the problematic class to exclude it or some other solution?

Comment: Please remove salutations/thanks from your question as per the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior